# Show/Hide thumbnail in loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

In wordpress loop a wanna make thumbnail toggle on link click.

Part of loop:

```
<?php $i++; ?>
        <?php $aktualnosc_meta = get_post_meta($aktualnosc->ID); ?>
            <div class="case_study_box col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="case_study_img">
                    <a id="displayText-<?php echo $i; ?>" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a>
                    <div id="toggleText-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display: none">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($aktualnosc->ID) ?>">
                        <?= get_the_post_thumbnail($aktualnosc->ID, 'full', []) ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText-<?=$i;?>");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText-<?=$i;?>");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>
```

It dont work. I click on "show" link but nothing happens. Can you help me?

Comment: So, you have a bunch of functions `toggle`, right?

Comment: Yes. Maybe i should add numer "i" to function name.

Comment: definetely u should add $i,but not in function name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know - whether you have one `toggle` function or bunch of `toggle` functions, both cases will not work. Try this:

```
<div class="case_study_box col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="case_study_img">
        <a id="displayText-<?php echo $i; ?>" href="javascript:toggle(<?php echo $i; ?>);">show</a>
            <div id="toggleText-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display: none">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($aktualnosc->ID) ?>">
                    <?= get_the_post_thumbnail($aktualnosc->ID, 'full', []) ?>
                </a>
            </div>
         </div>
```

And `toggle` function should be one only:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle(idx) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText-" + idx);
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText-" + idx);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Adding an argument is a __more__ reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

By the time your event handlers run, the page is entirely in the browser and does not have access to PHP variables, functions, etc.

So, you need javascript references to toggleText and displayText for each clicked item.  Here's one way.

```
function toggle(text) {
    // text is the dom element that was clicked on
    var ele = text.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
}
```

Then you will need to change your onclick to:

```
href="javascript:toggle(this);"
```

To pass the "text" dom element to the handler function.

Note that all of your id attributes are unnecessary if you use this technique.